# Create ##temp table and insert the rows to an existing table only wherever the columns match

Tags: sql, mapping, field, temp, openrowset

The flow of what I want to achieve is as per the below steps:

1. I have an Excel file (which has dynamic columns), however certain columns are static and don't change, however their position in the file changes
2. I have a table that was created based on the static fields in a specific sequence (let's call that table `tblBase`)
3. I wish to upload the data from the Excel file into a `##temp` table, and then from the `##temp` table append the data to existing table `tblBase`, however only data from those columns which have the same name in both the table (not considering the position the sequence of the columns)

My code:

```
USE [master]
GO

EXEC sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO

EXEC sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO

EXEC sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 0
GO

EXEC sp_MSSet_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1
GO

SELECT * 
INTO ##temp 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                'Excel 12.0; Database=C:\Users\NEW_01012023\Downloads\Report_SERVICES.xlsx; HDR=YES; IMEX=1',
                'SELECT * FROM [Base$]')
GO

-- This throws an error as the columns are not mapped 
-- and the table was created from a file which had the 
-- column names with in a specific sequence
INSERT INTO tblBase 
    SELECT * 
    FROM ##temp
```

An example is below

Excel file has the following name (let's call it basefile)

```
ID,
Entry Date,
First Name,
Last Name,
Portfolio Unit,
Demand State,
Demand Type,
Staffed Date
```

`tblBase` [initially created on the above base1)

```
ID,
Entry Date,
First Name,
Last Name,
Portfolio Unit,
Demand State,
Demand Type,
Staffed Date
```

Next basefile has the same fields however in the following sequence: (let's call it base2)

```
ID,  
Entry Date,  
Staffed Date,  
Last Name,  
First Name, 
Demand State,  
Demand Type,  
Portfolio Unit
```

My challenge is to insert the data from the `##temp` table that was created using `OPENROWSET` based on table base1 and now insert / append the data from the `##temp` table that is created using `OPENROWSET` based on table base2.

Comment: Hi - you need to explicitly list the columns, in the correct order, in both the INSERT and SELECT parts of your statement

Comment: Gotcha..!!! thank you so much for the quick answer and support... i just tried it and it worked.. !!! Kudos!